Return from multiple recursions
I’m doing leetcode 79 C++ solution, where you need to find word in 2D matrix. I’m doing it with backtracking

class Solution
{
private:
    vector<vector<char>> matrix;            //Пример того как можно создать глобальную переменную чтоб не передавать ее каждый раз в аргументах рекурсивной функции
    string word;

bool backtrack (int row, int col, int N,
                const int num_rows, const int num_cols, const int word_size, vector<vector<bool>>& map_been, bool& result)
    {
        if (word[N]==matrix[row][col])                                                  //Буква в матрице совпала с текущей буквой word
            {
                if (N==word_size or result)                                             //Base case: дошли до конца word
                    return result = true;

                //cout<<"Совпала "<<word[N]<<" N="<<N<<endl;
                map_been[row][col] = true;

                if (!result and col!=num_cols and map_been[row][col+1]==0)              //Идем вправо
                    backtrack(row, col+1, N+1, num_rows, num_cols, word_size, map_been, result);

                if (!result and row!=num_rows and map_been[row+1][col]==0)              //Идем вниз
                    backtrack(row+1, col, N+1, num_rows, num_cols, word_size, map_been, result);

                if (!result and col!=0 and map_been[row][col-1]==0)                     //Идем влево
                    backtrack(row, col-1, N+1, num_rows, num_cols, word_size, map_been, result);

                if (!result and row!=0 and map_been[row-1][col]==0)                     //Идем вверх
                    backtrack(row-1, col, N+1, num_rows, num_cols, word_size, map_been, result);

                map_been[row][col] = false;
            }

        return result;
    }

bool backtrack_v2 (int row, int col, int N, const int num_rows, const int num_cols, const int word_size, vector<vector<bool>>& map_been)
    {
        if (row<0 or row>num_rows or col<0 or col>num_cols or word[N]!=matrix[row][col] or map_been[row][col]==true)
            return false;

        if (N==word_size)                                   //Base case: дошли до конца word
            return true;

        map_been[row][col] = true;
        bool result =  backtrack_v2(row, col+1, N+1, num_rows, num_cols, word_size, map_been)       //Идем вправо
                    or backtrack_v2(row+1, col, N+1, num_rows, num_cols, word_size, map_been)       //Идем вниз
                    or backtrack_v2(row, col-1, N+1, num_rows, num_cols, word_size, map_been)       //Идем влево
                    or backtrack_v2(row-1, col, N+1, num_rows, num_cols, word_size, map_been);      //Идем вверх
        map_been[row][col] = false;

        return result;
    }


public:
bool exist(vector<vector<char>>& matrix, string word)
    {
        int num_rows = matrix.size();
        int num_cols = matrix[0].size();
        int word_size = word.size();
        vector<vector<bool>> map_been (num_rows, (vector<bool> (num_cols, false)));             //Можно еще писать * в саму matrix, чтоб не создавать map_been
        bool result=false;

        this->matrix = matrix;
        this->word = word;

        if (word_size> num_rows*num_cols)
            return false;

        for (int i=0; i<num_rows; i++)
            for (int j=0; j<num_cols; j++)
            {
                //cout<<"i="<<i<<" j="<<j<<endl;

//Первый способ - быстрее выходит из большого количества рекурсий при нахождении word//////////////////////////////////////////

                if (backtrack(i, j, 0, num_rows-1, num_cols-1, word_size-1, map_been, result))
                    return true;

//Второй способ - тоже самое через or (больше рекурсий)////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/*
                if (backtrack_v2(i, j, 0, num_rows-1, num_cols-1, word_size-1, map_been))
                    return true;
*/
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            }

        return false;
    }
};

On every recursion step I have 4 variants: go up, left, right or down, each step makes new recursion. I want to know how to end all of my recursions when I find a whole word (base case), because right now when I find it, the program continues count going left, right etc.
My question is how immidiatly exit from multiple recursions if I found right answer somewhere deep in one of them.
EDIT: I made 2 variants, 1st was mine, 2nd was suggested by molbdnilo.
But 1st variant works 20% faster (420ms vs 520). My new question is why :)

The way to stop the recursion is to pay attention to the return value. You return true when you find a match, but never use that value to stop recursive calls. Incidentally I think you would find the coding easier if you stopped passing result into the function. This is a value you are returning from the function, so just use the function return value and drop that parameter.

Did you ask this question on the LeetCode forums?  If so, could you please link that discussion here in your question.  If not, why not?

I've never tried multi-threading on one of those sites. My first solution would be to just multi-thread it. Split the rows up into chunks that are given to threads, then each row is traversed until the first letter of the word is found, then spawn more threads to look in each direction. If a true is ever returned, I would need a way to exit immediately, but that can't be too difficult.

You are saying it is slow but this is not like you are telling us how big your board and word are, right? What can be processed by modern hardware in 0.5sec is huge -> Are you anywhere close to that? On another note, your version of backtrack_v2 looks like it is managing indexes incorrectly.

@Atmo testcases are provided by leetcode site, they say 1 <= m, n <= 6
1 <= word.length <= 15, but I dont know how many testcases they are running (usually around 100).
You should try solve leetcode problems, its great tool to become a programmer

@john Thanx, I edited my question (function backtrack_v2) like you suggested, get rid of result in arguments. But why it works slowly than my 1st solution?

Whether these sites are useful or not is a controversial opinion here. You are not making a very strong point if in the code you come up with, you try to read the character of word at index word.size(), of if you do the same for a vector... Isn't the site telling you of these mistakes?

For the record, I have coded a taken your backtrack_v2, added corrections and minor changes and tried to run it on a 25x25 grid (i.e. >17x the number of chars compared to your largest board) and a 25-long word. It takes <1ms to calculate. -> It takes a lot more than 100 tests of your largest size for the exec time to reach 400ms, let alone 500ms with smaller tests.

Cont'd But without the ability to profile your code (impossible on these sites I suppose) or the complete list of tests to be sure it is not 1000 of them on absurd sizes, how do you expect us to tell you what is wrong? That is not how optimization is supposed to be done and at best, we will only be able to throw variations of your functions, hoping for 1 to have acceptable performance. See the issue?

Have you heard about longjmp?

Use the result of the recursions and return as soon as one is successful.
You can also move the validity checks to simplify the flow, and use the sizes of your arguments instead of passing them.
Here is a different suggestion:
bool backtrack(int row, 
               int col, 
               int N, 
               const vector<vector<char>>& matrix, 
               const string& word,
               vector<vector<bool>>& map_been)
{
    if (row < 0 || row >= matrix.size() || col < 0 || col >= matrix[0].size() || N > word.size()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (N == word.size()) {
        return true;
    }
    map_been[row][col] = true;
    bool result = backtrack(row-1, col, N+1, matrix, word, map_been)
               || backtrack(row, col+1, N+1, matrix, word, map_been)
               || backtrack(row+1, col, N+1, matrix, word, map_been)
               || backtrack(row, col-1, N+1, matrix, word, map_been);
    map_been[row][col] = false;
    return result;


Nice solution, but in future I will have to use a map (vector<vector> map_been) of the cells that are already used. How to update the map is roughly clear, but how to clear it if the recursion fails in this case?

Im updated my question with map_been vector to make my question above clear

That needs a bit of restructuring. See update.

Thx bro I got your solution.

One more question - does it worth to make global variables for: word, matrix, num_rows, num_cols, word_size, map_been and set them like that: this->matrix = matrix;
So you don't have to pass them to the recursive function every time. Does this speed up the program? In what cases should you do this? Only if the variable does not change within the recursion or?

Global variables aren't worth anything, they are a cost and often cause bugs that are hard to track down. Passing primitives, references, and pointers as arguments does not cost anything in practice.

Ok, but what if the first  backtrack(row-1, col, N+1, matrix, word, map_been)
will return true, other 3 backtracks will still be launched and will launch their sub-backtracks, isnt it?

You need to read about how || and && work in your favourite C++ book. It should be in one of the first chapters.

Yes, I basically know that if the first operand is true then the rest should not be run
But...
I updated my main question- now it have my initial backtrack and yours backtrack_v2
Yours is 20% slower on leetcode, can you please explain why?

No, but your original code has undefined behaviour from out-of-bounds indexing, so it's a pretty pointless comparison.

Just checked - it works, first backtrack 430ms vs yours variant 520ms
Anyway, thanks for your answers
